# how to check usb pendrive if it has bad sectors?

Tags: bad-sectors, usb-storage

I once saw a case when file copied to pendrive had small patch of zeros where normal file had data. Is there a way to check whole disk for this kind of errors and if possible disable bad sectors ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually bad sectors trigger an Error while copying. Any way run disk check on the drive with bad sector repair oprtion & see the log:

```
chkdsk /X /R dive_letter:
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the pendrive and go to properties in tools check for errors in the fix error option should be enabled

Answer (score 1):

on Windows disabling the "Quick Format" option should run a full disk scan for bad sectors.

on Linux there is a specific tool for this purpose:
[badblocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) ([detailed guide here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/badblocks))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can right-click on the drive on the Computer screen.  On the Tools window, you will see an option to check the drive for errors.  This brings up a dialog that allows you to optionally check for bad sectors.

Caveat:   This works in Windows 7.  I think it works similarly in Vista, but I'm not sure about WinXP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to verify the files after copying them to usb key? In my  opinion, the unreliable usb key should be physically destroyed, so that it does not get used accidentially.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac or OSX use this

first find the drive letter

```
diskutil list
```

Example /dev/disk2 is mine at 200GB

Then scan only for bad blocks

```
fsck_hfs -fn -S /dev/disk2
```

Repair with this

```
fsck_hfs -fy -S /dev/disk2
```